# Find single generator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let a, b  are non zero elements in a commutative ring with unity R. It is also given that R is euclidean domain. Consider quotient ideal (aR:b) of R and And R is PID hence quotient ideal is generated by single element.

Find single generator of quotient ideal (aR:b) .

Is there any need R to be euclidean domain or it is enough R to be PID?

Comment: I have never encountered the notation (aR:b) before, and "quotient ideal" doesn't explain it to me. What does it mean?

Comment: $x \in R : xb \in (a)$

Comment: For the single generator to exist, it's enough for $R$ to be a PID. The euclidean algorithm gives you a direct way to find the generator. It's $a/(a, b)$.

Comment: @Ayman Hourieh what is a/(a, b)  ... I am unaware about this notation